# Live feed RPi camera to TV

Tags: camera

I'm trying to get my RPi to live feed the RPi camera to a TV on boot.
I have already a simple program in python that just outputs the camera feed, but when I run this program on boot it doesn't show the camera feed.

Comment: A little more info will be needed here for us to help you Stijn.  Is the TV connected tot he Pi, or remote?  How is the Python app feeding the signal to the TV?  Is this a GUI-based application (QT, etc.) that runs in the X-Windows environment? Or, is it something else?  The more detail you can give (within reason) the more likely you'll get a good answer.  Looking forward to helping you on this!